# Include a package for some libs in Nrwl/Nx workspace

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl

It seems like in a Nrwl/Nx workspace there is only a single package.json file. Now if we have multiple applications, each dependent on different packages, then we have to include all of those package in the single package.json file and wouldn't that increase the size of all the apps when they're built? (presumable vendor.js file).

For example if app-1 depends on d3 and app-2 depends on ag-grid libraries, wouldn't both of these libraries be included for both app-1 and app-2 unnecessarily? When the user of app-1 visits the app, ag-grid wouldn't need to be loaded for them.

Am I correct in my understanding or am I missing something? If my assumption is correct, is there a way to solve this?

How about lazy loaded libraries? For instance an "admin" library which is only available to some users (with admin role) may need certain graphing packages, which wouldn't have to be loaded for all the users.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the benefits of using nrwl/nx is the single package.json file. Using a single package.json is great because when you need to upgrade something like rxjs you only have to do it once and your entire codebase it running on the same set of dependencies.

It doesn't effect the size of the compiled code because an app will only include the code it uses thanks to webpack bundling and tree shaking. So there is no risk of D3 showing up in a bundle for an app that doesn't use it. In actuality you could have every npm package listed in your package.json and it wouldn't effect your bundle size.

nrwl/nx is 100% intended to use only one package.json file. Don't try to break it up if you are using nx.

Comment: Thank you. I tested this by adding D3 to package.json and noticed that the size of dist folder didn't increase. I then used it in one of my lazy loaded libs and it seems like only the size of that lib in dist folder went up, which is great. Thanks again for clarification.

Comment: I would argue. Single package.json has significant downsides:

1. It grows dramatically when you have multiple apps for different platforms, so it's hard to manage those dependencies. I have separate angular web app, and Ionic mobile app. For mobile app I need ionic-specific dependencies that are not needed anywhere else. If I then need to refactor, or even remove one of the apps, it is painful to detect which depencencies in package.json it depended on.
2. It complicates deploy process. When server runs "yarn install", it loads tons of dependencies not needed for the actual build target

Comment: i used the default generator from nx, and it seems its giving me a separate package json for my apps

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is short-sighted.

Yes a single `package.json` is fantastic for development, it allows you to co-ordinate versions for all your dependencies and hoist them to the root. But when you want to deploy an application - you don't want to ship the dependencies for *every application in your monorepo*

In-fact there was an open [issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1518) about this exact problem on `nx` for quite some time.

### Solution 2022

Now you can use the `generatePackageJson` option in your `project.json` build target options, to create a `package.json` for each app you wish to deploy.

Note: this is not documented, but you can read about it in the linked Issue, and merged PR.

Comment: Indeed, here's the relevant [PR #4164](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/4164)